# Java variable scope

Tags: java, scope

when a variable is initialize both in local scope as well as global scope how can we use global scope without using `this` keyword in the same class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "global scope" in the context of Java. A code sample would go a long way for this question.

Comment: Why would you try to avoid using 'this'? That is the way to do it.

Comment: Given that Java doesn't *have* global scope, I don't understand the question. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 7):

```
class MyClass{
    int i;//1
    public void myMethod(){
        i = 10;//referring to 1    
    }

    public void myMethod(int i){//2
        i = 10;//referring to 2
        this.i = 10 //refering to 1    
    }    
}
```

**Also See :**

- [Shadowing Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html)
- [what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use `this` it will always be the local variable.

Comment: If there is no variable in local scope with the same name as a instance variable then you can use the instance variable with out the `this` prefix

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible without this. The phenomenon is called [variable hiding](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15).

Answer (score 2):

If you are scoping the variable reference with `this` it will always point to the instance variable.

If a method declares a local variable that has the same name as a class-level variable, the former will 'shadow' the latter. To access the class-level variable from inside the method body, use the this keyword.

Comment: If you are scoping the variable reference with this it will always point to the FIELD variable.

Comment: @Vladimir You are right. I've corrected that. It was a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class VariableScope {

    int i=12;// Global
    public VariableScope(int i){// local

        System.out.println("local :"+i);
        System.out.println("Global :"+getGlobal());
    }
    public int getGlobal(){
        return i;
    }
}
```