# Why is it not possible to shadow a local variable in a loop?

Tags: java, variables, scope, shadowing

I got this situation I can't understand about shadowing. For example the following code:

```
class Foo {
   int a = 5;
   void goFoo(int a) { 
       // No problem naming parameter as same as instance variable
       for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) { }
       // Now the compiler complains about the variable a on the for loop
       // I thought that the loop block had its own scope so I could shadow
       // the parameter, why the compiler didn't throw an error when i named
       // the parameter same as the instance variable?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can make a local variable shadow an instance/static variable - but you can't make one local variable (your loop counter) shadow another local variable or parameter (your parameter).

From the Java Language Specification, [section 14.4.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.4.3):

> If a name declared as a local variable is already declared as a field name, then that outer declaration is shadowed (§6.3.1) throughout the scope of the local variable.

Note the "field name" part - it's specifying that it has to be a *field* that is shadowed.

And from [section 8.4.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.1):

> The scope of a parameter of a method (§8.4.1) or constructor (§8.8.1) is the entire body of the method or constructor.
>
> These parameter names may not be redeclared as local variables of the method, or as exception parameters of catch clauses in a try statement of the method or constructor.

(It goes on to talk about local classes and anonymous classes, but they're irrelevant in your case.)

Answer (score 2):

```
void goFoo(int a) { 

       for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) { }

}
```

it is similar to

```
void goFoo() { 
       int a;
       for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) { }

}
```

so multiple declaration of `a` on the same scope, it is not acceptable.

or simply it is similar to

```
void goFoo() { 
  int a;
  int a;
}
```

**Also See**

- [java-variable-scope-shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560850/java-variable-scope#4560893)

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the variable depends on the hierarchy of the block as well.

ie if u use like this

```
void goFoo(int a) { 
       // No problem naming parameter as same as instance variable
       for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++) { }
       //Now the compiler complains about the variable a on the for loop
       // i thought that the loop block had its own scope so i could shadow
       // the parameter, why the compiler didnt throw an error when i named
       // the parameter same as the instance variable?

       int b; // you can do this.

   }
```

That is if a variable is declared in the outer block then you can not declare the same in the block which is inner. the other way you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

But you don't declare the second "a" in that new scope, as your code shows.  It's in the scope of the goFoo() block itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that the loop is shadowing the class field, the name is already used by the parameter.

Two options:  One is to change the loop:

```
for (a = 0; a < 5; a++) { }
```

This uses the parameter as the index variable.  Not clear why you would have a parameter, but all the same...

The other option is to rename the loop variable or the parameter to something else.

Answer (score 0):

It is not shadowing, it is a conflict here. Both `a` are in the method scope. One cannot define two variables of same name in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

In Java (unlike, say, in c++) you cannot declare a local variable when another local variable with the same name is "in scope".

You cannot do this in Java

```
void foo() {
    int a;
    {
         int a;  // You cannot declare 'a' here because a
                 // from the outer block is still in scope
                 // here. Local variables in Java cannot be
                 // shadowed by another local variable with
                 // the same name. Only instance variables 
                 // can be shadowed by the local variables 
                 // with the same name.
    }
}
```

However c++ allows you to do this

```
void foo()
{
    int a;
    a = 10;
    cout << a << endl;  // prints 10 duh
    {
        int a;   // this declaration shadows the local
                 // variable 'a' from the outer scope.

        a = 20;  // assigns 20 to the variable 'a' in
                 // current inner scope, like you'd expect.
        cout << a << endl;  // prints 20.
    }
    cout << a << endl;  // prints 10
}
```