# What have I done Wrong? Error is Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type double

Tags: android

```
    final EditText number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final TextView result =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

what have i done wrong?

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
```

number1 and number to cast double but i get the"Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type double" error

```
    double number1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());//error

    double number2 = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());error         

        result.setText(String.valueOf(number1*number2));
```

Comment: It is beacause of conflict with variable names, just change the names of your **double** or **EditText** variables and make the **EditText** variables global if you are using a saperate **OnClickListener**

Comment: apart from the mistakes pointed. Read this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623334/question-about-variable-scope-and-shadowing-in-java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 final EditText number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 final EditText number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

to

```
final EditText num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

And use

```
double number1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText().toString());
double number2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText().toString());
```

You had `EditText numberr1` and `double number1`

Using `MainActivity.this.varaiblename` to  refer to the variable declared and intialized outside `onClick`.

You may wan to check

[What is variable shadowing used for in a Java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class)

Found a better explanation @

[question about variable scope and shadowing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623334/question-about-variable-scope-and-shadowing-in-java)

Also have a try catch

```
try
{
final EditText num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

throws `NumberFormatException` if the string does not contain a parsable double.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have tow variable/instance with the same name. since you are trying to create instance of `EditText` and `double` with same name...that's why its giving you error.

Now, Change your variable name of `double` type as below...

```
double number1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());

double number2 = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());         

result.setText(String.valueOf(number1*number2));
```

to....

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());

double num2 = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());        

result.setText(String.valueOf(num1*num2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
double number1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());//error

double number2 = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());error
```

to

```
double number1 = Double.parseDouble(YourActivity.this.number1.getText().toString());//error

double number2 = Double.parseDouble(YourActivity.this.number2.getText().toString());error
```

You will also need to make the two `EditText` global variables. You are giving the same name to the `EditText` and `double` as a result the variables created in the method are shadowing the `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
final EditText editText1_number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText editText2_number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

Change your `EditText` name and try.

```
double number1 = Double.parseDouble(editText1_number1.getText().toString());
double number2 = Double.parseDouble(editText2_number2.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());

double num2 = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());        

result.setText(String.valueOf(num1*num2));
```

instead of

```
double number1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());

double number2 = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());         

result.setText(String.valueOf(number1*number2));
```

because already you have

```
final EditText number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

and you are using number1  and number2 wrongly!!