# Java this.classProperty versus classProperty incase argument variable name clashes?

Tags: java

Can someone please explain output 0 in case of first constructor without `this` ?

If the argument variable name is same as class property name and i am using that property inside the method. What does java interpret that "class property" or "the argument variable" ?

Without `this`:

```
 public User(int userId){
    userId = userId;

 }
```

With `this`:

```
 public User(int userId){
    this.userId = userId;

 }


 public void PrintUserId(){
    System.out.println(this.userId);
}

 User firstUser = new User(123);
 firstUser.PrintUserId();
```

// 0 without this

//123 with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can someone please explain output 0 in case of first constructor without this ?

Sure - this statement is a no-op:

```
userId = userId;
```

It just assigns the variable of the `userId` parameter *to itself*. It doesn't touch the field at all. Within the method, the parameter `userId` *shadows* the field called `userId` - so you have to *explicitly* say that you want to refer to the field, which is what the second version does:

```
this.userId = userId;
```

I'd expect any modern IDE to highlight the no-op assignment in the first version with a warning.

(It's worth being clear about terminology, by the way - an *argument* is a value provided to a method; a *parameter* is the variable which is declared as part of the method signature. Likewise it's a *field* rather than a *property*.)

EDIT: If the parameter has a *different* name, e.g.

```
public User(int id) {
    userId = id;
}
```

then the parameter *doesn't* shadow the field, and the identifier `userId` still refers to the field. It's all a matter of working out what the meaning of an identifier is - in your first example, the simple name `userId` refers to the parameter, which is what causes the problem.

EDIT: From [section 6.4.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1):

> Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be used to refer to the declared entity.
>
> ...
>
> A declaration d of a field or formal parameter named n shadows, throughout the scope of d, the declarations of any other variables named n that are in scope at the point where d occurs.

So in this case d would be the declaration of the formal parameter `userId`, and the scope of d is the constructor - so throught the constructor, the parameter shadows the field.

Comment: thanks but if i use public User(int Id){ userId = Id;}, It updates class property.

Comment: @talktopk: Yes, because in that case the parameter doesn't shadow the field.

Comment: so there is a preference i guess in case of clash.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was about to comment regarding Sun/Oracle's use of hiding vs shadowing but you've edited your answer already :)

Comment: @milkplusvellocet: Yes, I hadn't looked that in detail before. And now obscuring, too...

Answer (score 4):

This is because of [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class).

You're not assigning the parameter value `userId` to the member variable because it's being shadowed. Because `int` member variables are initialised to 0 that's why you're seeing that output without the `this` keyword.