# when we are calling the overriden method addFive() tha b is printed as Bar object is created but why it is calling "a" in Boo Class.Output is b3

Tags: java

```
class Boo {
    public int a = 3;

    public void addFive() {
        a += 5; 
        System.out.print("f "); 
    }
}

class Bar extends Boo {
    public int a = 8;
    public void addFive() { 
        this.a += 5;
        System.out.print("b " ); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boo f = new Bar();
    f.addFive();
    System.out.println(f.a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't override the instance fields, but only hide them. So, when you access an instance field on a `Boo` reference, you will get the one declared in `Boo` class only.

And when you increment the `a` in the `Bar` constructor:

```
this.a += 5;
```

It is incrementing the `a` declared in `Bar`, since it is hiding the field `a` declared in `Boo`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you used `Boo`

```
Boo f=new Bar();
```

reference and fields are not polymorphic

Answer (score 0):

The field `a` in Bar is *shadowing* field `a` in Boo. It's a separate field, but because it has the same name, you must reference the field in Boo by `super.a` to reach it from Bar.

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class) covers shadowing well.