# why I get nullpointerexception when I call methods of enum class in Java

Tags: java, junit, enums, nullpointerexception

Here is my simple `interface` and an `enum` that `implements` it. I have written a very simple `JUnit Test case`, which fails because of `NullPointerException`. I do not understand why this `Exception` is thrown. I have constructed an `enum` object in the test class.

```
public interface Account {
    public String getName();
    public boolean isBillable();
}

public enum NonBillableAccount implements Account {

    SICK_LEAVE("SickLeave"),
    VACATION("Vacation"),
    BUSINESS_DEVELOPMENT("businessDevelopment");
    private String leaveType;

    private NonBillableAccount(String leavetype) {
        this.leaveType = leavetype;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.leaveType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBillable() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And the `JUnit test case` here

```
public class NonBillableAccountTest {

    Account ac = null;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Account ac = NonBillableAccount.BUSINESS_DEVELOPMENT;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetName() {
        assertEquals(ac.getName(),"businessDevelopment");
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsBillable() {
        assertEquals(ac.isBillable(), false);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're shadowing your `ac` variable in your `setUp()` method. Remove `Account` in `Account ac = NonBillableAccount.BUSINESS_DEVELOPMENT;`.

Comment: Damn,I am doing this stupid for second time. why!!!!!!

Comment: No need to beat yourself up or get discouraged.  Everyone starts somewhere.  I still do amazingly stupid things in Python all the time, because I'm still learning the language.  As long as you're always @eagertoLearn, you're good to go. :)

Comment: I do stupid stuff in languages I've known for years because that's just how it goes - typos, whitespace, colons instead of semicolons... Sometimes the simplest mistakes are the hardest to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the `ac` field of the overarching class.  You are hiding it (actually known as [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) with a new `Account ac` variable.  To fix this, simply remove the `Account` type name before the variable assignment.

You can also refer to the variable with `this.ac`, but there's no need so long as you don't declare a variable with the same name in the local scope before you reference it.

Answer (score 3):

By referring to `ac` with the `Account` type modifier as follows you are causing it to be treated as a local variable:

```
// Create a local variable "ac", does not affect the class variable
Account ac = NonBillableAccount.BUSINESS_DEVELOPMENT;
if (this.ac == null){
   System.println('It does still equal null!'); // yep, it's null
}
```

Try this instead to set the `ac` property on your test class:

```
// refers to the class variable implicitly
ac = NonBillableAccount.BUSINESS_DEVELOPMENT;
```

**or**

```
// refers to the class variable explicitly
this.ac = NonBillableAccount.BUSINESS_DEVELOPMENT;
```

This is known as "shadowing" ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class)) which allows you to use the same variable names in different contexts. In your test methods it expands `ac` to `this.ac` in the compiler, which throws the NPE when you call `ac.getName()` as you have not set the class property yet.

Comment: No need for an explicit `this`.  That may confuse the OP about the concept of shadowing.  He could in fact use `this.ac` after declaring a new `Account ac` in the local scope to accomplish what he wanted.  He ought to be clear about how the actual hiding mechanism works to avoid this in the future.

Comment: True, I was trying to highlight the incorrect scope in the example by using `this` in mine but I see what you mean.

Comment: :)  Just want him to get what's going on instead of just making the code work this once. +1