# Java - "varible name" cannot be resolved to a variable - I cannot find where my error is

Tags: java, function

I have read the other questions with the same title but none have helped with my issue and nothing online has helped either.

I am new to Java and am trying to get a basic program running but I keep getting the aforementioned error.

Code below.

```
package loopy;
import java.io.*;

public class loopy {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // TODO: Use a loop to print every upper case letter
        for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
            System.out.println((char)i);
        }
        // TODO: Get input from user. Print the same input back but with cases swapped.
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          try {
            String input = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        toggleStringCase(input);


    }

    // TODO: Implement this function to return the opposite case of the letter given. DO NOT USE any built in functions.
    // How to handle the case where the char given is not a letter?
    private static char toggleCase(char c) {
        return c;
    }

    // TODO: Implement this function to toggle the case each char in a string. Use toggleCase() to help you.
    private static String toggleStringCase(String str) {
        return str;
    }

}
```

Where it says toggleStringCase(input); is where I am getting the error trying to pass the variable to a function.

Nothing i have read suggests what I might be doing wrong.

I am sure it must be a basic error  but could someone please point me in the right direction.

Have I missed some syntax somewhere?

Comment: Read about java scope -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732644/java-scope-of-a-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` only has scope in the `try` block, move the call there. Also, I would prefer a `try-with-resources` over explicitly closing `in` with another try block. **But**, it should be noted that closing `in` also closes `System.in` (which is a global variable) and great care should be taken in doing so (since any future attempts to read from `System.in` will fail)

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
    String input = in.readLine();
    toggleStringCase(input);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Eclipse added the try/catch automatically so I never thought it would affect the scope.

Answer (score 2):

variable `input` can't be solved to a variable since you don't have an `input` variable in the scope of your `main` method (the scope where you are using the `input` variable as a parameter of `toggleStringCase` method). You only have `input` variable in the scope of your `try` which means that `input` variable is only accessible within the `try` and since you are using `input` variable outside the `try` that is why it produces the error.

There are 2 possible ways to fix this:

- To fix this you should move your declaration of `input` variable in the scope of your `main` method. I have updated your code below:

```
package loopy;
import java.io.*;

public class loopy {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // TODO: Use a loop to print every upper case letter
        String input = ""; // DECLARE input HERE so that it can be used in the scope of your main method
        for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
            System.out.println((char)i);
        }
        // TODO: Get input from user. Print the same input back but with cases swapped.
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            input = in.readLine(); // get the actual input

        // The try/catch below are commented out since you can combine it to the try/catch above
        // START
        //} catch (IOException e) {
        //    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //    e.printStackTrace();
        //}
        //try {
        // END

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        toggleStringCase(input);


    }

    // TODO: Implement this function to return the opposite case of the letter given. DO NOT USE any built in functions.
    // How to handle the case where the char given is not a letter?
    private static char toggleCase(char c) {
        return c;
    }

    // TODO: Implement this function to toggle the case each char in a string. Use toggleCase() to help you.
    private static String toggleStringCase(String str) {
        return str;
    }

}
```

- Or you can move the function call for `toggleStringCase` inside your `try-catch`. Refer to the code below.

```
package loopy;
import java.io.*;

public class loopy {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // TODO: Use a loop to print every upper case letter
        for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
            System.out.println((char)i);
        }
        // TODO: Get input from user. Print the same input back but with cases swapped.
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            String input = in.readLine(); // get the actual input
            toggleStringCase(input); // MOVE IT HERE
        // The try/catch below are commented out since you can combine it to the try/catch above
        // START
        //} catch (IOException e) {
        //    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //    e.printStackTrace();
        //}
        //try {
        // END

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // toggleStringCase(input); // was moved inside try-catch


    }

    // TODO: Implement this function to return the opposite case of the letter given. DO NOT USE any built in functions.
    // How to handle the case where the char given is not a letter?
    private static char toggleCase(char c) {
        return c;
    }

    // TODO: Implement this function to toggle the case each char in a string. Use toggleCase() to help you.
    private static String toggleStringCase(String str) {
        return str;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to move your variable [input] to your scope.
cause you declare it inside a try block, but want to use out of the scope.

```
public class loopy {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // TODO: Use a loop to print every upper case letter
    for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
        System.out.println((char)i);
    }
    String input=null;
    // TODO: Get input from user. Print the same input back but with cases swapped.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        input = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    toggleStringCase(input);


}

// TODO: Implement this function to return the opposite case of the letter given. DO NOT USE any built in functions.
// How to handle the case where the char given is not a letter?
private static char toggleCase(char c) {
    return c;
}

// TODO: Implement this function to toggle the case each char in a string. Use toggleCase() to help you.
private static String toggleStringCase(String str) {
    return str;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

classic eg of scope problem. The var input is only accessible inside the try block or what is under the braces {} 
 Move your `toggleStringCase(input);` in the try block of input itself

```
public class loopy {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // TODO: Use a loop to print every upper case letter
        for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
            System.out.println((char)i);
        }
        // TODO: Get input from user. Print the same input back but with cases swapped.
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          try {
            String input = in.readLine();
            toggleStringCase(input); // moved

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Or you can declare String input outside try block with some default/init value like

```
String input = "default value";// moved
try {
    input = in.readLine();
    toggleStringCase(input); 
}
```