# How to initialize an array of objects within a constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, constructor, initialization

I am making a Battleship game. So far, I have a implemented a Location class and a Grid class (the Locations constructor has no parameters, but will have default values for all of it's instance variables). The Grid class has an instance variable that is a 2D Array of Locations like:

```
private Location[][] grid;
```

What I want to do is make a constructor for the grid class that will make a grid (a 2D array of Location objects) and initialize each Location.

This is what I have made so far:

```
public Grid()
{
    Location[][] grid = new Location[10][10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = new Location();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use a method to get a location within the grid and try to print it out.

```
public Location getLocation(int row, int col)
{
    return grid[row][col];
}
```

And attempt to use it in a the course's "tester" (and I have implemented a toString() method for Location objects)

```
Grid board = new Grid();
        
System.out.println(board.getLocation(0,0));
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Grid.getLocation(Grid.java:24)
    at GridTester.run(GridTester.java:9)
    at ConsoleProgram.main(ConsoleProgram.java:21)
```

Is there a way that I can properly initialize every object within the 2D Array in a constructor?

Comment: Where is the `grid`variable which you use in `getLocation` declared? It isn't the same `grid` you use in the constructor. You need to understand scope better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732644/java-scope-of-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance variable and local variable (in constructor) have the same name. Whenever you call the constructor the `grid` variable in the constructor is shadowing the instance variable. Remove the type declaration in your constructor, i.e. `Location[][]`

```
private Location[][] grid;

    
public Grid()
{
    grid = new Location[10][10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {  .....
```