# Is it necessary always call this in a constructor?

Tags: java, this

Let's say I created this class:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel{
    private JTextBox textBox;
    public Panel(){
        this.textBox = new JTextBox(10);
        add(this.textBox);
    }
}
```

And in my main:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Panel panel1 = new Panel();
        Panel panel2 = new Panel();
    }
}
```

In the class `Panel`, is it necessary to call `this` at every line, or can I leave it away? Or would it mess up the `Panel`s?

Comment: It is not necessary.  At least not in this case.

Comment: No, but it *is* necessary if you're passing in parameters with identical names to member attributes.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Would it be necessary if I could change something with a method to the `Panel`? Would the change apply to both of the `Panel`s?

Comment: If it is a `Panel` method (and based on the definition of the method), it should only affect that select `Panel`.

Comment: You are not *calling* `this`, you are *qualifying* the instance variables with `this`. And, no, there is no need to do that here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only necessary when you receive parameters that have the same name of the fields declared in the class:

```
public class Foo {
    int x;
    int y;
    public Foo(int x) {
        this.x = x; //here is necessary
        y = -10; //here is not
    }
}
```

Another weird scenario is when a subclass shadows a field from the super class. Here's an example:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    int y; //shadows y field in Foo
    public Bar(int x) {
        super(x); //calling constructor of super class
        super.y = -5; //updating y field from super class
        this.y = 10; //updating y field from current class
    }
}
```

More info about the latter: [Java Tutorial. Hiding Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html). Note that this is weird because you should avoid such scenarios. It is technically possible but makes the code harder to read and to maintain. Even more info on this: [What is variable shadowing used for in a Java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1092099/1065197)

Comment: +1 - Answer could be improved by referencing the phenomenon by it's technical name '**shadowing**' - '*when you receive [or create] parameters that have the same name of the fields declared in the class*'

Comment: @Rudi good point. Added it into my answer.

Comment: By making the argument to `Foo` constructor `final` it will be even more obvious that `this` is needed. Otherwise it will not even compile.