# Meaning of this in specific situation

Tags: java, this

I'm currently reading about the `this` keyword and don't understand why is it useful to do things like:

```
this.object = object;
```

(`object` is a random variable. I just don't understand why we do like, `this.xxx = xxx`)

Help me please!

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to specify that you want to assign the value to the *field*, rather than the parameter or local variable:

```
public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
       ^        ^
       |        \--- Take the value of the parameter
       \---- Assign to the field
}
```

If you just wrote:

```
foo = foo;
```

in the above, then it wouldn't do anything - it would be assigning the value of the parameter back to the parameter.

Another option, however, is to use a different parameter name instead:

```
public void setFoo(Foo newFoo) {
     foo = newFoo;
}
```

Now the field and the parameter have different names, so you don't need to find another way to differentiate between them.

Answer (score 0):

imagine having a setter like

```
private Object obj;
public void setObject (Object obj) 
{
    this.obj = obj;
}
```

this `this` scope the object to the class field otherwise with

```
    obj = obj;
```

you would be setting the same object to be the same object.