# Encryption Code

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am trying to write a simple piece of code to take a document and encrypt it then decrypt it. I got the encryption to work but for some reason it is using a different array to decrypt it. Here's my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EncryptAlpha 
{
    private static int key;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();

/**
 * Constructs a EncryptAlpha object and sets
 * it encryption key to k
 * @param k
 */
public static int EncryptAlpha(int k)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        k= 1+(int)(Math.random()*(100-1)+1);
        num.add(k);
        System.out.println(num);
    }
    for(int n=0; n<num.size();n++)
    {
        key=num.get(n);
        if(n==num.size())
            n=0;
    }
    return key;
}


/**
 * This method takes a String object and converts it into an
 * ArrayList of integers, where each integer is the sum of 
 * consecutive pairs of characters from str where the sum is 
 * one character's integer number value plus 1000 times the
 * integer value of the next character. If there are an odd
 * number of characters a ' ' is added as the last character
 * @param str theString to be converted
 * @return the ArrayList of integer values
 */
private ArrayList<Integer> convert(String str)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> converted = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        int k= 1+(int)(Math.random()*(100-1)+1);
        num.add(k);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i+=2)
    {
        char t1, t2 = ' ';
        t1 = str.charAt(i);
        if(i<str.length()-1)
            t2 = str.charAt(i+1);
        int x = (int)t1 + 1000*(int)t2;
        converted.add(x);
    }

    return converted;
}

/**
 * This method takes an ArrayList of integers where each integer 
 * is the sum of consecutive pairs of characters from the original
 * String where the sum is one character's integer number value 
 * plus 1000 times the integer value of the next character.
 * @param converted the ArrayList to convert back into a String
 * @return the 'original' String
 */
private String deconvert(ArrayList<Integer> converted)
{
    String str = new String();
    for(int temp : converted)
    {
        char t1, t2;
        t1 = (char)(temp%1000);
        t2 = (char)(temp/1000);
        str = str + t1 + t2;
    }

    return str;
}


/**
 * Converts the String str into an ArrayList of integers
 * @param str a message to be encrypted
 * @return the converted ArrayList<Integer>
 */
public ArrayList<Integer> encrypt(String str)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> converted = convert(str);
    for(int i=0; i<converted.size(); i++)
    {
        int temp = converted.get(i)*EncryptAlpha(key);
        converted.set(i,temp);
    }
    return converted;
}

/**
 * Converts the ArrayList of integers converted back into
 * the original message from which it was created.
 * @param converted the ArrayList to be decrypted
 * @return the original message
 */
public String decrypt(ArrayList<Integer> converted)
{
    String str = new String();
    for(int i=0; i<converted.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int n=0; n<num.size();n++)
        {
            key=num.get(n);
        }
        int temp = converted.get(i)/key;
        converted.set(i, temp);
    }
    return deconvert(converted);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Brownie points for anyone who knows why the name of
    // EncryptAlpha object is enigma.
    EncryptAlpha enigma = new EncryptAlpha();
    String message = "I really like robots.";

    // Test the private methods
    ArrayList<Integer> converted = enigma.convert(message);
    System.out.println(converted);
    String original = enigma.deconvert(converted);
    System.out.println(original);
    System.out.println();

    // Test the public methods
    ArrayList<Integer> encrypted = enigma.encrypt(message);
    System.out.println(encrypted);
    original = enigma.decrypt(encrypted);
    System.out.println(original);
}
```

The issue is, that I am using an array to store the values for the letter shifts but for some reason the encryption and decryption are using two different arrays. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. `but for some reason the encryption and decryption are using two different arrays. How can I fix this?` Then just use the same array to encrypt and decrypt. That's it, isn't it?

Comment: You aren't really even using arrays are you? More like `String` objects? Why not encrypt the file itself then decrypt the same one? Try first printing your file, encrypting the file, printing the encrypted file, decrypting it, then printing the decrypted file.

Comment: I should've worded it better. I only set up one array but it is changing the array before decrypting it.

Comment: @Pearlpoodle Where is your array which is holding the key for encryption and decryption? I don't see it in your codes.

Comment: You're encrypting and decrypting the file I thought? What are you doing with arrays? Encrypt the whole file, then after decrypt it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I did understand well your "issue", you have a misconception about field/local variable, here's a commented version of your code:

```
public class EncryptAlpha 
{
    private static int key;

    // let's call this one "num1"
    public static ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    // ...

    public static int EncryptAlpha(int k)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // this is *not* num1
```

This is called variable shadowing, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class) for example. You probably want to remove the local variable declarations (i.e. `ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();`)

Some reading:

- [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)
- [Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: How would you suggest I fix this? Should I get rid of the new array in public static int EncryptAlpha()?

Comment: If you want num to be "num1" in EncryptAlpha() then yes.