# Only returns an index of -1 when there is a match

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist

I am trying to get the index of an item in an array that is selectable in a list view.

The issue is that when I click on the item, it only returns the index of -1, which means that it doesn't match when in fact there should be a match.

What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.goldleaf.branden.goldleafcomics;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GlimpseListFragment extends ListFragment {
    List<String> glimpse = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<UniverseListing> universalListings = new ArrayList<UniverseListing>();

    public GlimpseListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_glimpse_list, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String url = "http://goldleafcomics.com/application/UniverseGlimpse.JSON";
        PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(getActivity(), new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                universalListings = new JsonConverter<UniverseListing>().toArrayList(s, UniverseListing.class);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Application Data Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ArrayList<String> glimpse = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(UniverseListing value: universalListings){
                    glimpse.add(value.universeGlimpse);
                }

                ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(UniverseListing value: universalListings){
                    titles.add(value.universeId);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                
            }
        });
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String value = (String)getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        int index = this.titles.indexOf(value);
        String value2 = Integer.toString(index);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), value2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `titles.get(position)` instead of using the adapter?

Comment: it doesnt return anything, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Then that perfectly explains why you get -1. The list is empty...

Comment: why would the list be empty if it is being used to show a list? and how would i be able to use the list to return the index?

Comment: Maybe start using the debugger or `Log.d` to print out some of the values you are trying to compare. How do you know the strings are perfectly matching?

Comment: checked the debugger and there is nothing in the list

Comment: you define glimpse two times, could you try to make those changes, List<String> glimpse;
and inside onCreate initialize it
 glimpse = new ArrayList<>();
and do the same for titles.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's your problem. Variable shadowing

Comment: so I write my comment as an answer and hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you define glimpse two times, could you try to make those changes,

```
List<String> glimpse;
```

and inside onCreate initialize it

```
glimpse = new ArrayList<>();
```

and do the same for **titles** and **universalListings**.

Comment: so as @cricket_007 mentioned in comments you should read about Variable shadowing, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class) thread very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these two sections of code. You are [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)  the member variables with local variables of the same name.

```
public class GlimpseListFragment extends ListFragment {
    List<String> glimpse;
    List<String> titles;
    List<UniverseListing> universalListings;
```

Later...

```
            glimpse = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(UniverseListing value: universalListings){
                glimpse.add(value.universeGlimpse);
            }

            titles = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(UniverseListing value: universalListings){
                titles.add(value.universeId);
            }
```

You don't need to initialize Arraylists with the class. You should typically lazily initialize them (in other words, when you need to)