# Why do we use 'this' in setter method but not in getter method?

Tags: java, setter, getter-setter, getter

For example, in the following code:

```
private int id;

public void setID(int ID) {
    this.id = ID;
}

public void getID() {
    return id;
}
```

Why don't we say `return this.id` in the getter function or conversely say `id = ID` in the setter function? Also is `this` actually necessary? I mean, aren't the functions called through an object, say `obj.setid(1)` or `obj.getid()`? Will it work differently if I don't use the `this` keyword?

Comment: Often in setters, you have a method argument with the same name as the instance variable that you are setting. In the code you posted, you called one `ID` and one `id`, but you could have called them both `id`. Then `this.` would be required to distinguish the instance variable from the method argument. If you call the two variables different things, you don't need `this.`

Comment: Here in this code, You don't need to use `this` keyword.

Comment: `this` is only required if a local variable name hides a field. Since your local variable in the setter (`ID`) is not the same as your field (`id`), `this` is not required at all. But variable names **shouldn't start with an uppercase letter** according to the Java Naming Convention, so change your variable quickly.

Answer (score 16):

You need to use `this` when the variable names are the same. It is to distinguish between them.

```
public void setID(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

The following will still work when `this` is removed. It is because their names are not the same.

```
public void setID(int ID) {
    id = ID;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

NO, we use it in both just in case the name of your attributes is same, your example not provide this case, so consider you have this :

```
private int id;

public void setID(int id) {
//                    ^^---------This instead of ID
    this.id = id;//<<------------So to make a difference between the attribute of method 
                               //and the id declared in the class we use this
}

public void getID() {
    return this.id;//<<<---------you can use this.id also here it is not forbidden
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We usually do this to avoid [DataShadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class) Because if you do below thing in setter (assuming your method parameter name is **id** instead of **ID**

```
public void setID(int id) {
   id = id; // You are reassigning the value to the same variable
}
```

whereas if you want to set the value in Instance level variable then you must use **this** keyword (which represent the current object)

**Note:** In your case **this** is not required as local and the instance level variable name is different.

Hope this clears your confusion

Answer (score 2):

When you have define a class and an object of that class,you need this to initialize in setter if the passed argument name and the attribute name of the object are same.

`public void setID(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}`

Basically this refers to the object through which the call is made.