# Can I use same name for public variable and method argument in java?

Tags: java, methods, arguments, public

So, can I use same name for public variable in a class and method argument in java?
for example("number" is declared twice):

```
public class Class1 {
    public int number;

    public static String function1(String id,int number)
    {
        //do something

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class

Comment: Yes, you can do so, technically, but the better question would be: Is that a good idea?

Comment: ok, I understand. The actual code which I wrote was working on my PC but I wasn't sure that it is going to work everytime and on every platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

The ***int number declared in the method*** is only accesible inside de method.

The ***int number declared as property*** in the class is accesible in any method for the class.

If you want to access to the ***number*** property inside the method, you must use ***this***.

Example:

```
public static String function1(String id,int number)
{
    this.number = number;
}
```

Comment: Please modify "If you want to access to the number variable inside the method" to "If you want to access to the number property inside the method" because the two are variable. People can get confused in my opinion :) The same in this phrase "If you want to access to the number variable inside the method, you must use this." change to property :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can because the two variables are in different scopes. The method argument is hiding the class attribute for the scope of the function. If you want to access the class attribute within your method anyway, simply use this.number instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if anyhow you have scope related problem then you can qualify the member using the reference `this`

```
public static String function1(String id, int number)
{
    this.number = number; 
    //here you assign the class member with the value of the parameter
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use same name for public variable and method argument in java but be careful in case of constructor

You cannot do like this

```
public class Car{
    String carname;
    int carspeed;

    public  Car(String carname , int carspeed){
        carname = carname;
        carspeed = carspeed;
    }

}
```

instead do this

```
public class Car{
    String carname;
    int carspeed;

    public  Car(String carName , int carSpeed){
        carname = carName;
        carspeed = carSpeed;
    }

}
```

or do this

```
public class Car{
    String carname;
    int carspeed;

    public  Car(String carname , int carspeed){
        this.carname = carname;
        this.carspeed = carspeed;
    }
}
```

even you can mix it

```
 public class Car{
        String carname;
        int carspeed;
    
        public  Car(String carname , int carSpeed){
            this.carname = carname;
            carspeed = carSpeed;
        }
    }
```

when you use same variable name for parameter inside constructor and your class property name then they throw error at compile time