# Java static variables and local variables

Tags: java, variables, foreach, static, local-variables

I am new in Java and came across one OCJA-1.8 sample question where I am having some doubt. I need clarification on this behavior of JVM.

```
 public class Test{

static int x=1;//**This is static class level variable**

   public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] nums={1,2,3,4,5};
    for(int x:nums){ // Local variable declared for for-each loop.
        System.out.println(x);
    }
  }
}
```

Why has the JVM not thrown an error for a duplicate variable for the variable which is declared inside for each loop 'int x'? As static variable has class level scope.

Comment: you should read scope of variables. Its nearly same in all language . FYI - class level, method level, block level etc.

Comment: That is called [Variable Shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class)

Comment: it is variable shadowing

Comment: The local variable always hides (shadows) the variable declared as "global" (class variables)

Comment: Change to `System.out.println(Test.x);` and you'll access the static variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local variable hides the original static field somewhat, but it is not inaccessible:

```
Test.x
```

And for non-static fields:

```
this.x // not in this case
```

So it is allowed, and in effect one often sees:

```
public class Pt {
    private final int x;
    public Pt(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Which prevents the need to introduce some convention (_x, mX).

What is not allowed:

```
void f() {
    int x = 42;
    if (true) {
        int x = 13; // COMPILER ERROR
        ...
    }
}
```

As this is bad style, causing confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The inner variable declaration of x override the static one.
If you need to access the static variable you can access it with `Test.x`

Answer (score 2):

The duplicate variable compilation error happens for two variables with the same name declared in the same scope : fields or method declaration scope.
In your example, each variable is declared in a distinct scope.
As a consequence, as you refer `x` in the method declaring `x`, by default it refers to the variable with the nearer scope available (the `x` local variable) that so shadows the other variable (the `x` field variable).

To reference the shadowed variable :

- if it is a static field (your case), prefix it with the class name declaring it : `Test.x`
- if it is an instance field, prefix it with the `this` keyword : `this.x`

Answer (score 1):

When you have a local variable same as static variable, static variable of the class is shadowed by the local variable.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't throw an error because Java has the concept of [**shadowing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class). In essence, the variable with the lowest [scope](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/) is used.

The static field is still accessible, you just need to fully qualify it:

```
for(int x:nums){
    System.out.println(x);       // Local x
    System.out.println(Test.x);  // static x
}
```

This can be confusing to a reader of your code and so should be avoided in most cases. If you find yourself with a field and local variable named identically, there's *probably* something up and you should re-evaluate how you've named your variables.

In your specific case, `x` is not a descriptive name and both variables would benefit from better, more descriptive names.

In certain cases, such as within a constructor or setter method, it's beneficial to have local variables and fields with the same names, and this is where shadowing is a useful feature.