# How can I access this m1() method in the following program?

Tags: java, methods

**How can i access the x = 15 value from m2() ?**
I am accessing following values as given in comment of the program.

```
  class A  {
        int x = 10;
        void m1(){
        int x = 15;     //How can we access x =15 ?

  class B{
        int x =20;
           void m2(){
            int x = 25;
            System.out.println(x);          //for x = 25
            System.out.println(this.x);     //for x = 20
            System.out.println(A.this.x);   //for x = 10
            System.out.println();           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [What is variable shadowing used for in a Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class) may answer your question. Long story short: you can't.

Comment: I think there's a misplaced closing brace somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't get access to `x` defined in `m1()`. To fix it, you could change the variable name: `void m1() { int a = 15; ...}`, or much better to use different names for all variables, because readability will be much higher (and at the first look, developer will not be hesitated what variable is used in every place):

```
public class A {
    private int a = 10;

    public void m1() {
        int m = 15;

        class B {
            private int b = 20;

            void m2() {
                int x = 25;
                System.out.println(x);  // x = 25
                System.out.println(a);  // a = 10
                System.out.println(b);  // b = 20
                System.out.println(m);  // m = 15
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`B` is an inner class inside `A`. So, when you want to reference the outer class, use `A.this`, you want to use `m1` from the outer class, so use `A.this.m1()`