# How to access outer class method local variable in local inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes, local-variables

```
public class MyClass {
    int x=9;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       MyClass  myClass = new MyClass();
       myClass.test();
    }

    public void test(){
        int x=10;

        class InnerClass{
            int x = 11;

            void print(){
               int x = 12;
               System.out.println(x); 
               System.out.println(this.x); 
               System.out.println(MyClass.this.x); 
               System.out.println("MyClass => test() => x :" + "?");
            }
        }
        InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass();
        innerClass.print();
    }
}
```

How to call MyClass `test()` method local variable *x* inside the InnerClass `print()` method. What i can write in place of *?* in last `System.out.println()` method in order to get the value of `test()` *x*.

Comment: Just because you call a datatype 'InnerClass', doesn't make it an 'inner class', this is just an instance variable, not an inner class.

Comment: just a thought: what is stopping you from passing that 10 value as parameter to the print method?

Comment: @Stultuske the class named `InnerClass` is not the instance variable, it is method-local inner class, because it's the class in the outer class method.

Comment: Duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48801326/how-can-i-access-this-m1-method-in-the-following-program/48801624#48801624

Comment: @EJusius nope. that makes it a 'local class', not an 'inner class'. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: @Stultuske, ok but i just want to know the scenario.

Comment: @AnkitKumar as I have asked before: what stops you from passing the correct value as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in `Java` you can't.

The only way to access the `x` in `MyClass::test` would be to rename both variables in your inner class and in your inner class method into something else.

There is no need though to rename the outer `class` field `x` as  `InnerClass::print` would consider the variable in the most-inner scope.

Although this snippet is for demonstration purposes, better practice would have you have different and more significant names for each variable.

Answer (score -2):

That works fine for me:

```
public class Outerclass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Outerclass outer = new Outerclass();
        outer.outerMethod();
    }

    // method of the outer class 
    void outerMethod() {
        int num = 23;

        // method-local inner class
        class MethodInnerClass {
            public void print() {
                System.out.println("This is method inner class "+num);
            }
        }
        // Accessing the inner class
        MethodInnerClass inner = new MethodInnerClass();
        inner.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: no doubt it does, but this doesn't reflect the code of the OP. in the code of the OP, there is also an instance variable with the same name.

Answer (score -3):

To print outer class variable use

```
 MyClass.this.x
```

Comment: Mr. Ankit Kumar asking how to access `test()` method variable `x`. Pay attention when you read the question :)

Comment: By using "MyClass.this.x" we will get the value of MyClass variable x. means this will return us 9. but i want to print x = 10.

Comment: @AnkitKumar that 10 is a local variable inside a method, so you are not trying to reach a variable inside the class. please learn about scopes before trying to do something like this.

Comment: @Stultuske ok, but i change the variable x to y then i am able to access the y inside the inner class method, means the variable is in scope.

Comment: @AnkitKumar if both an instance variable and a local variable have the same name, the compiler won't know what you mean, and take what it ('s programmed to) assume what you mean.