# Trying to create a Matrix with ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, matrix, arraylist, collections

Trying to create a matrix object of generic type that has int columns, rows, and values. *Note: The code below uses integer type to simplify.*

Example output:

```
21  703   22   23   

3   3   13  13  6
```

Or

```
   studone   studtwo  studthree

   studfour  studnine studten

   studran  studmoreran studplus
```

Attempt:

- Decided to create an ArrayList as it can be expanded in size
- My idea: Matrix will have col, rows... so rows of x ArrayList, and cols of y ArrayList

  - Not able to test the code but I feel there must be a better way, the for loop seems excessive?

Here is the constructor:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrixOne;

public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {

    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;

    matrixOne = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        matrixOne.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList>());
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)  {
        matrixOne.get(j).add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); 
    }

}
```

> ISSUE: When trying to add value to a particular row/col, I get the
>   following error in below method: **The method add(int) is undefined for the type Integer**

```
 // on method .add()      <-------- error
public void insert(int row, int column, int value) {
    matrixOne.get(row).get(column).add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are shadowing your field

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrixOne;
```

with

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>> matrixOne = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>>();
```

which doesnt have any type other than ArrayList. Try this :

```
matrixOne = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

for [shadowing a class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class)

Comment: I see, but wouldn't i been making it a type ArrayList instead of Integer... as in:  private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>> matrixOne;
    matrixOne = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>>();

Comment: Yes it is a type but probably its type that you wont be able to cast to integer. If you want an ArrayList of ArrayLists of ArrayLists, you better at least make type of the last one clear. Which should be Integer. ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> matrixOne = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();

Comment: So this is the confusing bit, do I need 3 levels of ArrayLists or just two, the question is regarding the approach and if there is a better way

Comment: Well, when you say a matrix, 2D is what comes to my mind. Which is simply a list of lists. That means that you can use a list as following ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix = ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

Comment: Okay, is the for looping the way to go to specify col and rows? ArrayList that is Matrix, has a row of ArrayList which has a Columns of ArrayList... in the code?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly. But the idea here is to create rows first. You can add the rows to your main List one by one. After you're done, you will have the rows and columns you need. But to be honest, if you have a fixed size of columns and rows, use a two dimensional Array instead.

Comment: It is a fixed sized rows/cols i.e. whatever is in the params of constructor. But can you give me an example of what a two dimensional array would look like, still not sure what the best solution is for this... this is confusing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array

Comment: Ahh I see! If I wanted to retrieve the value from the multi ArrayList how would I do this with your approach... Im trying:   return matrixOne.get(row).get(column)     ... But im not sure how to reach the actually element

Comment: **int a = matrix[i][j]** for _Two Dimensional Array_ and **Integer a = matrix.get(i).get(j)** for _ArrayList of ArrayLists_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167857/discussion-between-3yanlis1bos-and-shaz).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to use the dimensional array instead. Following is the simple implementation for transforming list(vector) to dimensional array. Inspired by R 's `matrix(vec,nrow = 3,ncol = 3)`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] vec = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    toMatrix(vec,3,3);//parameters: vector(list),row of expected matrix,column of expected matrix
}
public static int[][] toMatrix(int[] vec,int row ,int col){
     int[][] matrix = new int[row][col]; 
        int vecIndex = 0;//list index to pop the data out from vector
        //Vector to matrix transformation
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                if(vecIndex==vec.length) break;
                matrix[i][j] = vec[vecIndex++];//pop the vector value
            }
        }

        // Displaying the matrix, can ignore if not necessary
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){ 
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){              
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "   ");
            }
            System.out.println();
         }
        return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void insert(int row, int column, int value) {
    matrixOne.get(row).add(column, value);
}
```