# Why do I have to set AuthenticationManager twice

Tags: java, spring, extends, superclass

In my application I've implemented X.509 authentication

I created the following class named `X509AuthenticationFilter` that extends
[AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java) provided by spring security by default.

I added my own AuthenticationManager to the class

```
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager
```

And also included the following setter

```
public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
{
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}
```

The bean is initialized in the spring-security.xml like so:

```
<beans:bean id="x509AuthenticationFilter" class="com.example.sec.x509.X509AuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</beans:bean>
```

The bean named `authenticationManager` does exist and it's present in the spring context.

However, given such configuration I get the following startup error:

```
An AuthenticationManager must be set
```

For some reason the AuthenticationManager is deliberately set to null in the superclass. Later on `afterPropertiesSet()` gets called and unfortunately throws the exception.

The only workaround I came up with is changing the setter in my own class to the following:

```
public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
{
    super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added my own AuthenticationManager to the class

So you effectively [shadowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class) existing `authenticationManager` instance declared in [AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/feff7476693e47a1b28543521dae2bb79e8a1b3e/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java#L93).

If you don't need to access AuthenticationManager from within your `X509AuthenticationFilter`, just don't declare it. If you do, you will have to call super setter as you're already doing.

Maybe `authenticationManager` should be declared `protected` in `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`, which would resolve this situation cleanly ...

Comment: The catch is that I have to use the `AuthenticationManager` in own class to authenticate the user...  There's no method named `getAuthenticationManager()` in the superclass, otherwise I wouldn't have declared the variable and just used `super.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate()`. Is the absence of such method by mistake or design?

Comment: as I written, IMHO `authenticationManager` should be declared protected in `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` so subclasses (like yours X509AuthenticationFilter) can access it. Maybe worth [reporting issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/new?assignees=&labels=status%3A+waiting-for-triage%2C+type%3A+bug&template=bug.md&title=)